# Direct sum of real valued functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=\{f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ the vectorspace of the real valued functions, with $$U=\{ f \in V \ | \ \  f(0) = 0\} \text{ and }  W =\{f \in V \ | \ f\text{ is a constant function\}}$$
as subsets of $V$.

1) Show that $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$.

2) Show that $V$ is a direct sum of $U$ and $W$.

---

First question is not hard to answer I am mainly concerned about the second question. I tried to solve it like this:

Tere are two criteria for showing that a vectorspace is a direct sum of two others.

1. $U \cap W =\{f_{0}\}$, where $f_{0}(x) = 0\ \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. $V = U +W$

The first one is pretty obvious because its the only function that fits both properties.
For the second one with have to show a set equality with $(V \subset U + W) \wedge (U + W \subset V)$

1. "$U + W \subset V$"

This one is pretty straightforward because $V$ is a Vectorspace and $U$ and $W$ are subspaces, so that every linear combination ist in V aswell.

2. "$V \subset U + W$"
   Here is where I am not quite sure if I am doing the right thing:

Let $f \in V$, we are observing $f(0)$ and there are two things that can happen.

If $f(0) = 0$, we have nothing to do because then $f \in U$.

If $f(0) \not= 0$, then we can split $f$ in two parts.

One part define as $h(x)$ is the part of the equation which is dependent of the value of x. The other part $g(x):=f(0)$ is the constant value for $f(0)$.
$$f(x) = h(x) + g(x)$$
I defined $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ in such a way that $h(x) \in U, g(x) \in W$.
Therefore an element in $V$ is also an element in $U+W$

---

My main problem is splitting f up in two parts do I ned to say more about why that works or is this proof written in an believebale way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is well written for the last part you could go with this method :

Let $f \in V$, let $(g, h) \in U \times W$ such that $g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$ and $h(x) = f(0)$. $g \in U$ because $g(0) = f(0) - f(0) = 0$ and $h \in W$ because $h(x) = f(0) \in \mathbb{R}$ thus :

$g(x) + h(x) = f(x) - f(0) + f(0) = f(x)$

We have showed that any element of $V$ can be written as a sum of an element of $W$ and an element of $U$ therefore $U + W \subset V$

Answer (score 2):

Given any $f \in V$ let $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ and $h(x)=f(0)$ for all $x$. Then $g \in U, h \in W$ and $f=g+h$.